Erase Paint Unable clear paint and Image in Canava With Multiple Canavas Layer
I have wrote paint app using flutter, unable erase the whatever i have drawn please help to me.
We have provided sample code of below. Below code are the paint drawn and erase functionality not working below code. Eraser we are using white color but it was another drawing drawn time it was not appearing. Sample code below i have attached.
class MyPaintWithConfig extends CustomPainter {
  final List<CanvasLayer> layers;
  final PaintConfig currentLine;
  final List<Offset?> layerOffsets;
  final int currentLayerIndex;

  MyPaintWithConfig({
    required this.layers,
    required this.currentLine,
    required this.layerOffsets,
    required this.currentLayerIndex,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Draw the background if the base layer (first layer) is hidden
    if (layers.isNotEmpty && !layers[0].isVisible) {
      canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
        Paint()..color = Colors.white,
      );
    }

    // Draw all layers
    for (int i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
      final layer = layers[i];
      if (!layer.isVisible) continue;

      final offset = layerOffsets[i] ?? Offset.zero;

      canvas.save();
      canvas.translate(offset.dx, offset.dy);

      if (layer.selectedImage != null) {
        final image = layer.selectedImage!;
        // Draw image maintaining its aspect ratio
        _drawImageWithAspectRatio(canvas, image, size);
      }

      for (final line in layer.lines) {
        final paint = Paint()
          ..color = line.color!
          ..strokeWidth = line.strokeWidth!
          ..style = line.paintingStyle!
          ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(line.blurStyle!, line.blurSigma!)
          ..strokeCap = line.strokeCap!
          ..strokeJoin = line.strokeJoin!;

        if (line.image != null) {
          canvas.drawImage(line.image!, Offset.zero, paint);
        }

        if (line.points!.isNotEmpty) {
          final path = Path()..moveTo(line.points!.first.dx, line.points!.first.dy);
          for (final point in line.points!) {
            path.lineTo(point.dx, point.dy);
          }
          canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
      }

      canvas.restore();
    }

    if (currentLayerIndex >= 0 && currentLayerIndex < layers.length) {
      final currentOffset = layerOffsets[currentLayerIndex] ?? Offset.zero;
      canvas.save();
      canvas.translate(currentOffset.dx, currentOffset.dy);

      final currentPaint = Paint()
        ..color = currentLine.color!
        ..strokeWidth = currentLine.strokeWidth!
        ..style = currentLine.paintingStyle!
        ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(currentLine.blurStyle!, currentLine.blurSigma!)
        ..strokeCap = currentLine.strokeCap!
        ..strokeJoin = currentLine.strokeJoin!;

      if (currentLine.image != null) {
        _drawImageWithAspectRatio(canvas, currentLine.image!, size);
      }

      if (currentLine.points!.isNotEmpty) {
        final path = Path()..moveTo(currentLine.points!.first.dx, currentLine.points!.first.dy);
        for (final point in currentLine.points!) {
          path.lineTo(point.dx, point.dy);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, currentPaint);
      }
      canvas.restore();
    }
  }

  // Method to draw image with aspect ratio maintained
  void _drawImageWithAspectRatio(Canvas canvas, ui.Image image, Size canvasSize) {
    // Get the aspect ratio of the image and canvas
    final double imageAspectRatio = image.width / image.height;
    final double canvasAspectRatio = canvasSize.width / canvasSize.height;

    double drawWidth, drawHeight;
    Offset offset;

    if (canvasAspectRatio > imageAspectRatio) {
      // If canvas is wider than the image, fit by height
      drawHeight = canvasSize.height;
      drawWidth = drawHeight * imageAspectRatio;
      offset = Offset((canvasSize.width - drawWidth) / 2, 0); // Center horizontally
    } else {
      // If canvas is taller than the image, fit by width
      drawWidth = canvasSize.width;
      drawHeight = drawWidth / imageAspectRatio;
      offset = Offset(0, (canvasSize.height - drawHeight) / 2); // Center vertically
    }

    final Rect srcRect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());
    final Rect destRect = Rect.fromLTWH(offset.dx, offset.dy, drawWidth, drawHeight);
    final Paint paint = Paint();
    canvas.drawImageRect(image, srcRect, destRect, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}


